# AJAX pagination, pages not clickable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a problem with ajax pages. In the index file I have this pagination code:

```
<div id="pagesn">
<?php
    require_once 'libs/db.class.php';
    require_once 'libs/global.inc.php';
         $query="select count(*) as tot from table";
          $countset=$db->runquery($query);
          $count=$db->get_row($countset);
          $tot=$count['tot'];
          $page=1;
          $ipp=3;
          $totalpages=ceil($tot/$ipp);
          echo"<ul class='pages'>";
          for($i=1;$i<=$totalpages; $i++)
          {
              echo"<li class='$i'>$i</li>";
          }
          echo"</ul>";
        ?>
</div>
```

and here is AJAX code:

```
$("#pagesn .pages li").click(function(){
        //show the loading bar
        showLoader1();  
        $("#pagesn .pages li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});                
        $("#resn").load("data1.php?page=" + this.className, hideLoader1);
    });

    // by default first time this will execute
    $(".1").css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});
    showLoader1();
    $("#resn").load("data1.php?page=1",hideLoader1);
```

Main problem is that php code is in the index file, so it cant update without refresh, so it means when I add new entries, page numbers not updating. I tried to add this code to other file and load with jQuery into the same div:

```
$('#pagesn').load('data.php');
```

After that, pages updating automaticaly, but then they become unclickable, what causes that problem?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: The "unclickable" problem should at least get solved with using .on(). What else is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you add and remove `li` elements dynamically,then for attaching '`click`' handlers, you need to use [**.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('#pagesn').on('click','.pages li',function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#pagesn").on("click",".pages li",function(){
        showLoader1();  
        $("#pagesn .pages li").css({'background-color' : ''});
        $(this).css({'background-color' : '#A5CDFA'});                
        $("#resn").load("data1.php?page=" + $(this).attr("class"), hideLoader1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of the .on() function](http://jqapi.com/#p=on):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

So using `.on()` instead of `.click()` will make sure your handler function is executed even on elements that you are inserting after your code was executed.

```
$('#pagesn').on('click','.pages li',function(){
  // Do something ...
})
```